# phpactiverecord - Users::find('all') return empty array - version 0.0.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

i am using codeigniter latestversion and i have installed phpactiverecord version 0.0.2,

however when i retrieved data from database with this method

```
$users = Users::find('all') // return nothing

i did       var_dump($users); 

output::
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Users)[39]
      public 'errors' => null
      private 'attributes' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
        array (size=9)
          'id' => null
          'username' => null
          'email' => null
          'password' => null
          'active' => int 0
          'activation' => null
          'ip' => null
          'created' => null
          'lastaccess' => null
      private '__dirty' (ActiveRecord\Model) => null
      private '__readonly' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
      private '__relationships' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '__new_record' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean true
  1 => 
    object(Users)[40]
      public 'errors' => null
      private 'attributes' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
        array (size=9)
          'id' => null
          'username' => null
          'email' => null
          'password' => null
          'active' => int 0
          'activation' => null
          'ip' => null
          'created' => null
          'lastaccess' => null
      private '__dirty' (ActiveRecord\Model) => null
      private '__readonly' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
      private '__relationships' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '__new_record' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean true
```

i am trying to figure out what is the problem ,,, any help please

```
///// Model
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}



/* End of file user.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/user.php */
?>





///// Controller
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index()
    {

        $user = Users::all();

        var_dump($user);

            foreach ($user as $u) {
           echo $u->username.'<br/>';
    }

        ## Rendering the view
        $this->template->view($this->temp, array('page'=>'backend/users'), NULL);
    }

}

/* End of file users.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/users.php */


?>




////// Autoload
$autoload['sparks'] = array('php-activerecord/0.0.2');
```

Comment: So it “returns nothing”, but dumping the variable gives you exactly what you expected? How are you otherwise determining that it returns nothing, then?

Comment: the array is empty, it should contain data from database.....even though when i echo  $u->username , nothing appears

Comment: The username is `null`, so nothing’s going to appear. (It’s a PHP thing. Escape while you can.) Seems like the problem is how you’re saving records, not reading them.

Comment: i am just getting data , i am not saving ,

Comment: i just don't know why it's not working, i just decided to use php-activerecord, and i am just following the documentation but no luck....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `__construct()` function entirely from the `Users` model